# PHP : cannot remove empty array

Tags: php, arrays

im trying to remove only the empty array

```
Array
(
    [test1] =>  test1
    [test2] =>  test2
    [test3] =>  
)
```

i have tried the following :

```
$array = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $array));
```

and

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
    if( is_array( $value ) ) {
        foreach( $value as $key2 => $value2 ) {
            if( empty( $value2 ) ) 
                unset( $array[ $key ][ $key2 ] );
        }
    }
    if( empty( $array[ $key ] ) )
        unset( $array[ $key ] );
}
```

also i have tried to avoid adding any empty array :

```
foreach($attributes_array as $key => $single_attribute){
 if(!empty($attributes_array)){
  $attributes[$attributes_array[$key]['attribute_name']] = $attributes_array[$key] ['attribute_value'];     
 }
}
```

any of the following code wont work in my case, any other possible soultion?

Answer (score 1):

If your definition of empty is the same as `empty()` you can use `array_filter` without a callback:

```
$array = array_filter($array);
```

Otherwise you can define a callback function to use with `array_filter` for your empty rules:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($val) {
    return $val !== '';
});
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/lGhUC

Comment: i have tried using this code but no luck, the issue is the third place in the array ( [test3] => ) @cOle2

Comment: @davidasor Is the third element really empty? The above code appears to work: https://3v4l.org/mX7RA